# Reformatting a date column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using a market data API and am using Pandas dataframes to filter and restructure before storing in a database. Before it goes into InfluxDB, I need to restructure a date column which currently looks like:

| Earnings |
| --- |
| May 15/b |
| Apr 09/a |

What I have so far is below, but I'm getting the error -

```
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/OMT/Demo/scratchpad.py", line 41, in <module>
    filtered['NewEarnings'] = pd.to_datetime(filtered['NewEarnings'], format='%b%d')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 801, in to_datetime
    cache_array = _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 178, in _maybe_cache
    cache_dates = convert_listlike(unique_dates, format)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 460, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 423, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    result, timezones = array_strptime(
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/strptime.pyx", line 144, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime
ValueError: time data '-' does not match format '%b%d' (match)
```

The code in question -

```
filtered = df
earningsColumn = filtered['Earnings'].squeeze()


stripped = earningsColumn.str.rstrip('. /a/b')


filtered['NewEarnings'] = stripped



filtered['NewEarnings'] = pd.to_datetime(filtered['NewEarnings'], format='%b%d')
```

Comment: What format do you need the date to be in?

Comment: Ideally,
%m%d%Y

Comment: Year is missing. How to solve it?